# Ввод названия файла Python

Tags: python-3.5

Приветствую.
Суть такова: Пользователь вводит название файла, после чего вводит текст файла.
Но суть в том, что он может ввести такие символы как "/ \ @" и т.п., что может положить приложение. Тобишь название поста используется в момент создания файла. Например: "post#1\43". Т.к. в папке "data" не существует такой папки - выбьет ошибку. Как этот недочёт исправить? Прилагаю часть кода.

```
    nameFile = input("Введите название поста: \n")
    textOnPost = input("Введите текст поста: \n")
    file = open("..\journal\data\\" + nameFile + ".txt", "w")
    file.write(textOnPost)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно просто ловить ошибку, которая произойдет, если ОС не смогла открыть или создать файл с таким названием:

```
def create_file():
    nameFile = input("Введите название поста: \n")
    try:
        file = open("..\journal\data\\" + nameFile + ".txt", "w")
    except OSError as e:
        print('Ошибка при создании(открытии файла): ', str(e))
        return
    textOnPost = input("Введите текст поста: \n")
    file.write(textOnPost)
    file.close()
```

Но дело в том, что в таком решении будут отлавливаться все ошибки, связанные с открытием/созданием файла, а не только связанные с названием.

Можно написать функцию, которая будет проверять, есть ли в названии файла запрещенные символы (в таком случае вы можете добавить еще и дополнительно свои, если хочется):

```
def is_correct(filename, forbidden_symbols):
    for i in forbidden_symbols:
        if i in filename:
            return False
    return True

nameFile = input("Введите название поста: \n")
if (is_correct(nameFile, "\\|/*<>?:")): # набор запрещенных символов символов для Windows
    textOnPost = input("Введите текст поста: \n")
    file = open("..\journal\data\\" + nameFile + ".txt", "w")
    file.write(textOnPost)
    file.close()
else:
    print('Введите корректное название файла.')
```

Ну или использовать регулярные выражения:

```
import re

nameFile = input("Введите название поста: \n")
forbidden_symbols = "\\|/*<>?:"
pattern = '[{0}]'.format(forbidden_symbols)
if (re.search(pattern, nameFile)): # набор запрещенных символов символов для Windows
    textOnPost = input("Введите текст поста: \n")
    file = open("..\journal\data\\" + nameFile + ".txt", "w")
    file.write(textOnPost)
    file.close()
else:
    print('Введите корректное название файла.')
```